# Exposing a Pipe from an external module in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-module, angular-library

I'm working on abstracting some utility libraries that we use in our projects.
I've created a new Angular library which exposes some models, services and pipes.

I need to be able to use a pipe either in a template and inside a component.

This is my library structure:

**Shared Module**

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    BytesPipe
  ],
  declarations: [
    BytesPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    BytesPipe
  ]
})
```

**ByesPipe**

```
   @Pipe({
          name: 'bytes'
        })
        export class BytesPipe implements PipeTransform {         
          transform(input: any): any {
...

         }
        }
```

Builded the library, I do the import in my application:
**App.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [SharedModule], 
  exports: [SharedModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Everithing works fine if I use BytesPipe in a template.
When I try to use the Pipe inside a component I receive this compilation error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'shared/lib/pipe/bytes.pipe'
```

The only way to get the things work is do this import instead of 'shared/lib/pipe/bytes.pipe':

```
import {ɵe as BytesPipe} from 'shared'
```

The content of 'shared.d.ts' is:

```
export * from './public-api';
export { BytesPipe as ɵe } from './lib/pipe/bytes.pipe';
```

I know that this way to import is wrong, since I'm referring to the compiled name that could change withing different builds.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it's only alias issue, i think everything is working as you expect, because in your shared file you exported it as 'ae' so  to use it in other files you are going to reference to the Alias which's 'ae', however it can have also an Alias

Comment: Yes, everithing works fine using alias, but I need to expose the pipe with its current name, not the alias, which may vary from build to build. 
Also I don't want that a developer that uses my library need to know what the alias name is to use the library.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was so simple: I needed to export the pipe explicitly on public_api:

```
export { BytesPipe } from './lib/pipe/bytes.pipe'
```

Comment: What file is that line in?